# how can I increase my workflow of making cloud shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Basically I have been using the Pen Tool to create cloud shapes similar to the image below. I feel it can be a bit time consuming. Isn't there any way I can increase my workflow of making such shapes using another approach or a plugin (not too expensive)?

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is a bad answer, but can't you save the paths and add it onto another project? Then, you can mask out the part you don't want?

Answer (score 5):

The Shape Builder might be the best friend you never knew you had, here. It's a tool that allows you to add shapes together easily and quickly, even better than the Pathfinder does. Create a group of objects, select them, and select the Shape Builder tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>). Drag to add shapes together and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-drag to exclude them.

In this cae, you could first set up a grid of horizontal lines, with lots of circle shapes repeated horizontally. Those would be the building blocks you can use to build your cloud shapes with:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I followed your instructions. I created one circle in a grid and transformed it to give me a row of circles but the ungroup has been grayed-out. How can I make each of circles individual objects?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow that question. What I did was draw the horzontal lines, one circle and copy that over and over (`Ctrl/Cmd + D`) and then use the shape builder.

Comment: I rather used the transform effect to make the other circles. All my circles (in a row) where seen as one object. I wanted to separate them but I couldn't.

Comment: ah! then you'll want to `Object > Expand Appearance` that group to actually turn them into actual objects.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the effect you have. My shapes are quite different and I am not sure where they are (I can't find them in the objects in the layer). Here is a screenshot [Grid for Shapes](http://imgur.com/4ZlfbQs) of what I've done

Comment: You are definitely on the right track. See that there's one united object standing out there? Don't forget to zoom in and add all the tiny shapes as well.

Comment: Some of the smaller shapes can't be added.

Answer (score 2):

here's the old way using path finders

1. draw some round cap paths

[image]

2. add more round cap paths, to use as negative space

[image]

3. select all paths and go to Object->Expand->Stroke

[image]

4. draw some rectangles where you want to connect the green clouds

[image]

5. select the rectangles and the green clouds, apply Unite PathFinder

[image]

6. select both your new shape plus your negative space beige shapes and apply Minus Back PathFinder

[image]

7. done

[image]