# Creating Dripping Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I create this effect in Photoshop?

It appears to be something dripping downwards and is sourced directly from the V-Sauce3's youtube channel.

[image: V-Sauce Banner Image]

Could someone let me know? Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Attempted to create guides with rounded squares but that just wasn't optimal for doing multiple 'drips' per say.

Comment: Does it have to be Photoshop? Because the basic shape was definitely done in Illustrator.. maybe then it was imported to photoshop

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what you tried, preferably including a screenshot. I'm sorry if I sound rude, but we're not a 'request a tutorial' website. Please put as much effort in your question as you'd expect a good answer to take. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a drip pattern but rather an audio "level meter" motif. This looks like two layer masks using multiple copies of the capital I from the font used for the word "sauce" with a few lower case i glyphs thrown in. One mask is upside-down. Search using the `[layer mask]` tag

Answer (score -1):

Theres a couple of techniques in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51184/how-can-i-increase-my-workflow-of-making-cloud-shapes) that might help. Both involve creating the shapes with basic geometric shapes and the pathfinder tool:

One of them involves creating rounded rectangles or expanded rounded strokes, joining them with square shapes, and then deleting round areas from the joins to make all the ends rounded.
[image]

The other technique involves making a grid out of overlapping circles and joining and deleting them with the pathfinder in order to make the needed shapes. 
[image]

Comment: post this [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51184/how-can-i-increase-my-workflow-of-making-cloud-shapes) if you have anything else to add so you can get your rep but if this is a copy to the other answers that is why I downvoted it.